# Error Finding Home page for Drupal 7 Site on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: installation

I installed Drupal more or less successfully in /var/www/html on Ubuntu Linux. However when I go to 'localhost' it still just shows the Apache home page. However, if I go anywhere WITHIN my drupal site it works fine. So the home page is the problem. In fact if I click 'home' in the admin toolbar it takes me (again) to the apache home page.

Here's what I set in my 000-default.conf file on Ubuntu:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    . . .
    ServerName  mysite.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried following the directions here but didn't see any reference to index.htm or .html in my apache2.conf file:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1484514

Not sure what else to try.

Suggestions?

Comment: Purpose of Stack Exchange sites is not giving suggestions, but  answering a well-defined question. We cannot debug a site we don't have access, and listing all the possible causes, hoping to hit the exact one, is not the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you install drupal? in the `/html` folder? If so, perhaps you need to delete index.html (inside /html folder) which is the page you are seeing. Or did you do `/var/www/html/drupal`?

I installed my drupal in `/var/www/drupal` (I created the drupal folder inside `/www` and left the `/html` folder alone, untouched).

then in  000-default.conf I have:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal

<Directory /var/www/drupal/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

[image]

Comment: ok, so I have done exactly what you have above except my site is localhost/mysitename instead of mysite.com. I've also changed my links to images and so forth within my drupal site to /sites/default/etc...' and I cleared the cache multiple times. i still just see the image placeholders on every page. when i inspect element the links say /sites/default/etc... on every page. and yet it's not working. Note: I also have a link to my home page on my site that doesn't work. The link url is '/' and when the link is clicked it takes me to a page of folders that shows sitename and html.

Comment: Good grief, nevermind. I didn't restart apache after doing the changes. Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable php in your apache conf. You can try

```
$ sudo a2enmod php5
```