# Image shows on home page but not other pages

Tags: media

I've added an image to a block that shows on every page and have the image added manually in the block like so:

```
<img src="sites/default/files/image-name" />
```

It shows fine on the home page as intended, but on the interior pages it doesn't show. I inspected element and for most pages it's using the same URL to try and access it.

I cleared cache.

Thoughts on why this might be?

Comment: That's how HTML work. You hardcoded it as a relative link, so if it appears on `example.com/somearticle`, browsers are obligated to look for image at  `example.com/somearticle/sites/default/files/image-name` - and this path does not exist.

Comment: @Molot right...but, I thought in Drupal this always worked. Well, I guess I just have to make it absolute then. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: Drupal is just a glorified HTML generator. At the end of the day, html will work like html always does. [`image_style_url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) is a Drupal way around this particular problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <img src="sites/default/files/image-name" />
> ```

right now its appending after the url of whatever page you are on.

```
yourwebsite.com/hello/sites/default/files/image-name
yourwebsite.com/article/sites/default/files/image-name
yourwebsite.com/contact-us/sites/default/files/image-name
```

instead of appending after your domain name.

```
yourwebsite.com/sites/default/files/image-name
```

so you just need to add a `/` at the beginning, so it appends after your domain name only.

**so your code needs to be:**

```
<img src="/sites/default/files/image-name" />
```

Comment: yes, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: ok, so I thought that's what was needed and I'm pretty sure that's what I've done before. But when I put my links in like this the image placeholder shows up and not the image on every page. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Nevermind i fixed it. it's because the whole site is in a sub-directory and i need to reference that ALSO, like so: /sub-dir/sites/etc.

Comment: you shouldn't need to ref your sub directory. Did you setup your 000-default.conf correctly? see my answ in [Error Finding Home page for Drupal 7 Site on Ubuntu Linux](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176402/error-finding-home-page-for-drupal-7-site-on-ubuntu-linux) I put my site inside a folder called Drupal.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. I setup my site in /var/www/sitename which is why I guess I have to reference it in my links now. But I think I see what you mean. I could just put that whole path in my 000-default.conf and add additional sites also. I'll just try that. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the block has permission to display content with internal pages also like block display might have been set as the  only.

Comment: thank you, it does. I just went ahead and made the links absolute and that fixed the problem.

Comment: absolute links are sometime so much pain in the ass especially when you move your site to different server. All your links need to be updated so I suggest use relative links

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to have image in block you can use image block module. Its pretty easy to use.

Comment: thank you that's also a good idea I had not considered. What I was looking for specifically is above.